# HttpRequestHeaders.Add splits the header on a whitespace

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, http-headers, httprequest, string-formatting

I'm trying to add a new header to a request I already had (which worked before), in which I want to put some sort of User-Agent string formatted like this:

> **AppName**/**AppVersion** (**DeviceOS** **DeviceOSVersion**)

The code for it is written like this (request is a `HttpRequestMessage`):

```
request.Headers.Add(UserAgentKey, $"{AppName}/{DependencyService.Get<IVersionProperties>().GetAppVersion()} ({Device.RuntimePlatform} {DependencyService.Get<IVersionProperties>().GetOSVersion()})");
```

But weirdly enough it splits the string in two parts on the withspace (between the appverion and the opening parenthesis) resulting in 2 values for the User-Agent header instead of 1 unified whole.

So I'm curious what I'm doing wrong here, I think it has something to do with the whitespace and I might need to escape it somehow, but I'm not sure how. I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a full-on solution, but at least a workaround, why not compose the string first: `var userAgent = $"{AppName}/{DependencyService.Get<IVersionProperties>().GetAppVersion()} ({Device.RuntimePlatform} {DependencyService.Get<IVersionProperties>().GetOSVersion()});"`

And then take out the newlines: `userAgent = userAgent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");`

As for the cause, I would say that one of these values has a newline in it. Although I don't really see why or which. Did you inspect each of the values individually?

Answer (score 0):

## Apparently it had to do with the header I was using.

I used the header "User-Agent" which expects a certain format and has some other funny business attached to it, when I changed it to "User-Agentt" for example it worked just fine and since I don't explicity need the header to be called that I will just change the name of the header.